# Unable to copy from tmux (2.4+) to the OS X clipboard

Tags: osx, tmux

The following code used to work in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
# Mac OS X:
bind-key -n -t emacs-copy M-w copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"

# Move tmux copy buffer into x clipboard
unbind-key M-w
bind-key -n M-w run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -selection clipboard" \; display-message 'Copying to clipboard'
```

It stopped working just recently, so I can't copy text anymore from tmux to elsewhere.  I am guessing this is the result of upgrading tmux or `reattach-to-user-namespace`.

I now get the following error:

```
invalid or unknown command: bind-key -n -t emacs-copy M-w copy-pipe 
"reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

Here are the versions I am using (from `brew`).

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tmux/2.4/bin/tmux

/user/local/bin/reattach-to-user-namespace/2.5
```

What may have changed, and how can I go about restoring my ability to copy from `tmux` to the system?

Comment: What port or package system are you using? With MacPorts tmux and the pasteboard software can both be installed via `sudo port install tmux tmux-pasteboard`

Comment: Thanks @thrig I'm using `brew`. I updated the OP.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following instead:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode M-w send-keys -X copy-pipe 'reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy'
```

Note that `tmux` [recently changed](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/909) key tables:

> - Key tables have undergone major changes. Mode key tables are no longer   separate from the main key tables. All mode key tables have
>     been removed,   together with the -t flag to bind-key and unbind-key.
>
>   The emacs-edit, vi-edit, emacs-choose and vi-choose tables have been
>     replaced   by fixed key bindings in the command prompt and choose
>     modes. The mode-keys   and status-keys options remain.
>
>   The emacs-copy and vi-copy tables have been replaced by the
>     copy-mode and   copy-mode-vi tables. Commands are sent using the -X
>     and -N flags to   send-keys. So the following:
>
>   bind -temacs-copy C-Up scroll-up
>     bind -temacs-copy -R5 WheelUpPane scroll-up
>
>   Becomes:
>
>   bind -Tcopy-mode C-Up send -X scroll-up
>     bind -Tcopy-mode WheelUpPane send -N5 -X scroll-up
>
>   This changes allows the full command parser (including command
>     sequences) and   command set to be used - for example, the normal
>     command prompt with editing   and history is now used for searching,
>     jumping, and so on instead of a custom   one. The default C-r binding
>     is now:
>
>   bind -Tcopy-mode C-r command-prompt -p'search up' "send -X search-backward '%%'"
>
>   There are also some new commmands available with send -X, such as
>     copy-pipe-and-cancel.

Comment: Hi Amelio! Tried your solution but without success. I'm using tmux 2.5 on MacOS with reattach-to-user-namespace installed. Both installed through brew.

Comment: Also, my goal is to get vi bindings and not emacs

Answer (score 0):

As Amelio mentioned in the other answer, `tmux` in version `2.4` had undergone major, backwards incompatibile changes when it comes to handling keyboard shortcut maps.

The way how I got copying to work with `vi` keys and version `2.6` is:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy'
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi V send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Y send-keys -X copy-end-of-line
```

You should be able to use similar syntax to bind the right commands for yourself.